# Starting docker service with a specific container on Ubuntu

Tags: docker

I am using docker on ubuntu and I have some containers with different projects.

Each time I start docker (`sudo service docker start`), all my containers are started and I just would like to start one specific container. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your container restart is handled depends on the restart policy you use when your launch your container. This is passed through the `--restart` option to [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Basically:

- no option or `--restart no`: Do not automatically restart the container when it exits. This is the default.
- `--restart on-failure[:max-retries]` : Restart only if the container exits with a non-zero exit status. Optionally, limit the number of restart retries the Docker daemon attempts.
- `--restart unless-stopped`: Restart the container unless it is explicitly stopped or Docker itself is stopped or restarted.
- `--restart always`: Always restart the container regardless of the exit status. When you specify always, the Docker daemon will try to restart the container indefinitely. The container will also always start on daemon startup, regardless of the current state of the container.

Answer (score 1):

I used this command in order to stop launching automatically my containers when I start docker :

`sudo docker update --restart=no container_name`

and it works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sure... you can run something like :

sudo docker exec -it **[interactive]** frosty_brahmagupta **[container name]**  bin/bash **[here is what you want to run on docker ]**

to see all your container you can run, even the inactive ones

docker ps -a

Comment: he wants to start a container, not to run a process in the container

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: ok, but if you do something like docker exec -d  frostly_brahamagupta will not run this container?

Comment: The question is basically: "how do I automatically start a selected container when my machine boots?". `docker exec` will run a command in an already running container which was previously launched with `docker run`. So once again, this is not at all answering OPs question.